# Is there a way to loop through rows of data in excel with python until an empty cell is reached?

Tags: python, xlrd

I am working with a large excel chart. For each row of data I need to perform several tasks. Is there a way to construct a loop in python to run through each line until an empty cell is found?

For example:

```
Project1  Data Data Data
Project2  Data Data Data
Project3  Data Data Data
Project4  Data Data Data
```

In this scenario, I would want to run through the chart until after `Project4`. But different documents will have various sized charts so it will need to run until it hits an empty cell, not limited by a specific cell.

I am thinking a `Do until` (as you can tell I don't know python very well) type loop would be useful. I also know there is a way to attempt empty cells via openpyxl which I am using for this project.:

```
if sheet.cell(0, 0).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
   # Do something
```

Currently, I would try to figure out a way to do something similar to this, unless someone suggests a better alternative:

```
    For i=10 to 1000 in range:
      #setting an upper limit of 1000 rows
        if sheet.cell(0,i) <> xlrd.empty_cell.value:
            variable = sheet.cell(2,i).value 
            #other body stuff
        Else:
            break
```

I know this code is rather undeveloped, I just wanted to ask before going in the wrong direction. I also am unsure how to assign i to run through the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to read the excel in python, I'd recommend taking a look at [pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pandas uses xlrd internally, why not use it directly?